# Форма подвисает при запуске метода

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть форма на котором несколько элементов. Основной это `MainBrowser`. Реализацию поиска данных на форме делаю через таймер, потому что так надо) В общем когда найден определенный текст на форме я хочу сделать диалоговый прелоадер, но это чуть позже. Изначально сделал чтобы отображался `LoadingIcon`, но форма подвисает почему то. Я думал если я его в отдельный поток пихну, то все будет без фризов работать.

```
MainTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
MainTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
MainTimer.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  {
   //   Если страница содержит определенные текст.. то
   // Запускаем метод
   Thread th = new Thread(Run);
   th.Start();
  }
  public void Run() {
   MainTimer.Stop();
   MainBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
   LoadingIcon.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
    LoadingIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   }));
  }
```

**Форма**

```
  <Grid MinWidth="700" MinHeight="500">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="459*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <WebBrowser x:Name="MainBrowser" Margin="10" Source="{x:Null}"/>
        <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Content="Завершить сеанс" Margin="220,0,220,9" Grid.Row="1" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="CloseButton_Click" IsTabStop="False" FontSize="14"/>
        <Label x:Name="LayoutBox" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,7" Grid.Row="1" Width="40" FontSize="14" MouseDown="LayoutBox_MouseDown" Cursor="Hand" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ToolTip="Язык ввода">
            <Label.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF044204" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF69FF69" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Label.Background>
        </Label>
        <Ellipse x:Name="CertState" Fill="#FFFD5353" Margin="0,0,10,10" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="21" StrokeThickness="0"/>
        <fa:ImageAwesome x:Name="LoadingIcon" Icon="Spinner" Spin="True" Margin="0,0,169,7" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="46" Visibility="Hidden"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: LoadingIcon.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke - тут вы перенаправляете задачу обратно в поток UI

Answer (score 0):

поиск по тексту и занимает много времени
попробуй что-то такое:

```
MainTimer.Tick += (os, eae)=>
{
  string s = //присвоить текст
  Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
  {
     //поиск текста
     if(страница содержит определенные текст)
       Run();//текст метода можно вставить сюда если он не нужен где-то еще
  }
}
```